# Three.js changing the color of a child object in a group on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a cube, a group is created inside it, and spheres are created in it. Can you please tell me how to correctly track the hover of the mouse on a specific sphere (with name "editMeshHelper"), so that later I can change its color? (via raycaster and inspectobject). There can be many parent objects on the stage

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYTdv.jpg)

```
Object { uuid: "4D446AF5-A180-42B0-AF2B-B6528FF787F1", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: {…}, children: (1) […], up: {…}, position: {…}, rotation: {…}, quaternion: {…}, scale: {…}, … }
​
animations: Array []
​
castShadow: false
​
children: Array [ {…} ]
​​
0: Object { uuid: "5A747510-6684-4DB2-8CC7-F8D5576B7412", name: "shperesForMeshEdit", type: "Group", … }
​​​
animations: Array []
​​​
castShadow: false
​​​
children: Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​​​
0: Object { uuid: "84923043-86FE-46B4-AE40-8D2774FBBD3F", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
1: Object { uuid: "0429E1D8-7D18-4DB1-93D5-5D5A4A7C3A67", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
2: Object { uuid: "D9E3BE5C-694A-4320-855B-00D9E2596FF4", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
3: Object { uuid: "D7A134F4-A4C9-4E38-925D-8939FB6C02D2", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
4: Object { uuid: "CE9111CB-2B3F-4736-80F8-0D1387C0ED62", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
5: Object { uuid: "D6A1176A-099D-4DFE-925F-4CA25421B622", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
6: Object { uuid: "E6C8BABB-489C-4C80-A0F1-0951E4EA6D0A", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
​​​​
7: Object { uuid: "14C7E8AA-3A2A-48AE-897B-A49717597AC9", name: "editMeshHelper", type: "Mesh", … }
```

Comment: See source code [in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes)

Comment: yes i saw this example but it doesn't work with child objects in a group

Comment: It should work the same. When using `.intersectObjects()` just make sure you set [the recursive argument to `true`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects) and it should find all descendants.

Comment: when i make the value true i get the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: INTERSECTED.material.emissive is undefined" in
INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
Inserted is null

he does not see spheres in the group

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0ymo4wzb/ - my source code